# How to iterate multiple links in python-requests?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests

here i am sending one url only and response of `page` is `200`. and data gets extracted.

when i try to send multiple links using a file the `response` is `400`

code for single url:

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
import html
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
#cars = [] # gobal array for storing each car_data object
url='http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/1969-ford-mustang-mach-1-manual/SPOT-ITM-225034'
car_data={} # use it as a local variable
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = (requests.get(url, headers=headers))
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
if tree.xpath('//tr[td="Badge"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()'):
    badge = tree.xpath('//tr[td="Badge"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()')[0]
    car_data["badge"] = badge   
if tree.xpath('//tr[td="Series"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()'):
    car_data["series"] = tree.xpath('//tr[td="Series"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()')[0]
if tree.xpath('//tr[td="Body"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()'):
    car_data["body_small"] = tree.xpath('//tr[td="Body"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()')[0]
#cars.append(car_data) #Append it to global array
```

output :

```
{'badge': 'Mach 1', 'body_small': 'Fastback', 'series': '(No Series)'}
```

code i tried for multiple links :

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
import html
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


cars = [] # gobal array for storing each car_data object
f = open("file.txt",'r') #file.txt would contain all the links that you wish to read
#This for loop will perform your thing for each url in the file
for url in f: 
    car_data={} # use it as a local variable
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    page = (requests.get(url, headers=headers))
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    if tree.xpath('//tr[td="Badge"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()'):
        badge = tree.xpath('//tr[td="Badge"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()')[0]
        car_data["badge"] = badge
        print(car_data)
    if tree.xpath('//tr[td="Series"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()'):
        car_data["series"] = tree.xpath('//tr[td="Series"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()')[0]
    if tree.xpath('//tr[td="Body"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()'):
        car_data["body_small"] = tree.xpath('//tr[td="Body"]//following-sibling::td[2]/text()')[0]
    cars.append(car_data) #Append it to global array
```

file.txt :

```
http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/1969-ford-mustang-mach-1-manual/SPOT-ITM-225034
http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/1969-ford-falcon-gtho-phase-i-xw-manual/SPOT-ITM-222630
http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/1969-ford-falcon-xt-auto/SPOT-ITM-222613
http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/1969-ford-falcon-xt-manual/SPOT-ITM-222612
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the lines in a list, then iterate this list to implement the loop. Use `with open`, it will automatically close the file when reading is done.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    #read file without newlines 
    urls = f.read().splitlines()
for url in urls: 
    ...
```